# id value and oper attribute mixed up while deleting row from a jqgrid

Tags: jquery, spring, jqgrid

what could be the reason of this error?

i have a jquery grid with somedata on it, while deleting a row from that grid. It gave me row id as `67878oper=del`    why this type of value for id?? it should give id as `67878` and `oper=del`..  But it is giving `id=67878oper=del`

jqgrid js code

```
$("#prepItemGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#prepItemGridPager',
{                                                               
    "del" : true,
    </r:secure>
    "excel" : false,
    "pdf" : false,
    "csv" : false,
    "refresh": true,
    "search":false
}, 
{
    "drag" : true,
    "resize" : true,

...
...
```

calls action controller

```
$('#prepItemGrid').jqGrid(
                    'setGridParam',
                        {
                        editurl:'editPrepItem.json',
                        datatype : "json"
                        }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

editPrepItem Action method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "editPrepItem")
    public String editPrepItem(PrepItem prepItem, ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam(value = "oper", required = true) String operation)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test");
        if (operation.equals("del")) {
            // Delete the recipe and reduce the noOfRecipe based on the prepItem
            // recipe id.
            System.out.print(prepItem.getId());//id is coming link this  67878oper=del

        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: may be you missed the space between the 2 attributes i guess, could you post the relevant code here, we can check

Comment: post the relevant code.

Comment: Provide your html and javascript code, looks like you missed some closed quote or so

Comment: @dreamweiver `may be you missed the space between the 2 attributes` where ?

Comment: @Jai i updated my question with answer. Please help

Comment: @Pavlo i updated my question with answer. Please help

Comment: @vikas What does the closed tag `</r:secure>` mean inside jqGrid?

Comment: `prepItem.getId();` could you post the definition of this

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, check the request and see what is being sent over. If the raw Http request looks broken, then it's the grid config, otherwise it's the controller. You need to post all your grid config if you want help looking at that. 
I've never seen that random secure tag used... What is it supposed to do? I'd take that out and give it another go.